# Split string with PHP Wordwrap in to two strings?

Tags: php, xml-parsing, query-string

Having a function that writes an XML, Problem is that values can't exceed 30 characters. In this scenario i need to split strings value and maintain readability.

Wordwrap can solve this but i don't believe it's the right solution?

First of all i need to determine if this is needed

```
    $name = 'My name is very long'

    // over 30 characters?
    if (strlen($name) < 30) {

        $this->xml->writeElement('Name', $name);
        $this->xml->writeElement('Name2', '');
}
```

In the case that it exceed 30 characters i would like to do something like

```
   else {

      // Divide $name between Name & Name2 maintaining readability, like
      $newname = wordwrap($name, 30,........ 

       // If i could end up with something like this 
       $this->xml->writeElement('Name', $newname1);
       $this->xml->writeElement('Name2', $newname2);
}
```

Am unsure what approach and solution is the best, Have been digging around much and feels like none of the ways i found is optimal for my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

You can use `wordwrap()` combined with `explode()` to create an array, which you then can simply loop through an insert the values into your xml, e.g.

```
<?php

    $name = "your string foo foo foo foo foo bar";
    $arr = explode(PHP_EOL, wordwrap($name, 30, PHP_EOL));

    foreach($arr as $k => $v) 
        $this->xml->writeElement("Name" . ($k == 0 ? "":$k+1), $v);

?>
```

Comment: It would give me  Name1 and Name2,  I need it to be Name and Name2 not Name1

Comment: Would this be the correct solution or is it anything else that i should use? 

if ($k < 1) {
  $this->xml->writeElement("Name," . $v);

 } else {

  $this->xml->writeElement("Name2," . $v);

 }